# Unit of measure for raw data in mne.RawArray

Tags: python, mne-python

I am trying to load EEG data from a `numpy` array into an `mne.io.RawArray` object. What is the correct unit of measure for the data in the array? Volts?

I read the source for [`mne.create_info`](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/blob/master/mne/io/meas_info.py#L1410), and it looks like the unit should be volts. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volts. The MNE-Python documentation has been updated: https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/pull/3972